# Local ajax file not being found in reactjs project

Tags: php, ajax, reactjs

I am having a problem with a practise project I am trying to write in Reactjs. This is just a basic react project, I'm not using flux or anything. The project has been set up using create-react-app.

I'm just trying a simple procedure to get some mock data from a local json file (using axios library). The idea eventually is to build a php file that can return data or update a mysql database. The trouble is, that react keeps saying "404 not found" on the local file in question.

Example :

```
    axios.get('./ajax.json')
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            });
```

All I get is "404 not found" on the ajax.json file. I have tried different ways of referring to it, but all I get is "Not found".

Eventually, I would like the React app to communicate with a php class that I have written via ajax, so that it saves information to a local database. The "ajax.json" file that I am using was just a quick thing for testing purposes. I have tried with a php file as well, but I have the same result.

I am running the app with "npm start" - I'm wondering whether this has something to do with it. I can't find instruction anywhere on how to communicate with local php files using the built in react server (that is used with npm start).

I have managed to make a successful ajax call from the fakejsonplaceholder website, but this is using an http:// call, not a local one.

Is there some kind of special way of doing this with React? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your React application is running in your browser, which doesn't have access to your filesystem. If you could fetch files directly from the browser, you would have a major security issue on your hands. You either need to serve your json data from a server, or I would recommend copying the json data into http://myjson.com/ which will give you a url that you can fetch, for testing purposes.

Comment: Ah ok, yes I understand. I suspected it may be something similar, however, I haven't quite got my head around it yet, but I think I understand what you're saying. So - if I put my database and my php files on my remote server and do it this way, this would work, yes? So I'll be using "http://MYSERVER/MYPROJECT/ajax.php" or similar to refer to in my react app?

Comment: I'm not well versed in PHP, but what your saying sounds correct. As long as the files are exposed by some url then you should be able to fetch it with `fetch` or `axios` etc

Comment: I've actually moved my test json file to my server, and a test php file. And I'm still getting error on the ajax call. Checking "Network" on the browser developer tools, the files are being accessed, the url is correct. When I console log the returned data, axios gives me an error which reads "Network error" - with no other information.

Comment: I'm now trying it using jquery and getJSON - if I use this file - "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1" from the fake api site, I get success. If I use the json file from my remote server, I get a failure. I can't seem to get any kind of clue as to what the error code is.

Comment: can you access the JSON file just by going directly the url in the browser?

Comment: Yes I can, it displays perfectly.

Comment: Are you allowed to post the url? If I can access it then I can probably help you more directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether is a definitive answer, but I just started mucking around in the end, and found success when I put my json file in my "public" folder of my project.
Thanks a lot azium I really appreciate your comments.

Comment: That's what the upvote button is for! Glad you figured it out :)

Comment: There's a delayed xmas upvote for you there! Sorry, I'm new here :D